# timsort or manually maintaining a sorted sequence, which is more efficient?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am developing a heuristic routine and need to maintain a sorted sequence/array/list. I heard that timsort is fast for maintaining order for sequences with subsequences that are already sorted.

On the other hand, what I need is pretty simple. After initially sorting the sequence, I need to repeatedly do one of the following at each step:

1. delete the min element.
2. visit each of the smallest `K` element.
3. insert one element and maintain order.

`timsort` seems to have a best-case complexity of O(n). Naively, I can implement operation 3 by calling `timsort` to get O(n). But these operations need to be repeated many many times. I was wondering if manually maintaining a sorted sequence (array or list) or doing a partial_sort at each step would be faster, and if so, what are the complexities.

For disclosure, I use c++, and examples in c++/c++11 where necessary would be nice.

Thanks,

Comment: could you batch together jobs? i.e. put several of the new elements together and sort them, remember several items to be deleted and delete them all at once? Or is that what you're asking?

Comment: no, I can't, because the steps that follows depend on which element is the smallest, or is deleted. So the insertion/deletion has to be done element-wise.

Comment: When you say "manually maintain", do you mean cache the data after you sort it and work with that the next time around instead of resorting it every time? Because "manually" to me means going through the data by hand and clicking "delete" :P

Comment: oh. By manually, I mean, e.g. maintain a `std::vector` or list in c++, make it sorted (once in the beginning), and then do a binary search to find a insert location for a new element to be included. I've done this sort of things in the past. This is manual to me, compared to call `std::partial_sort` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the best approach would be to actually use a self-balancing binary search tree. This should handle inserts/deletes in O(log N) and iterating over the k-smallest elements in O(k) if I'm not mistaken. Unless you have some reason you must use a list.